# Group by date by day and group of hours

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have aa session activity table with date.

```
sess_actv (id number,actv number,start_date TIMESTAMP(3))
```

I want sum of activity by day and my work hours(8am-8pm), off hours (the rest). So for every day I'll get 2 rows, group of work hours and group of day hours.

like this:

```
select sum(actv), 'work/off hours'
from sess_actv
group by 'work and off hours';
```

example table data

```
id      actv        start_date 
---     -----       ------------
1       2           21-NOV-13 2.30.02.358 am    
2       4           21-NOV-13 10.30.02.358 am
3       7           21-NOV-13 2.30.02.358 pm
4       1           21-NOV-13 10.30.02.358 PM
5       7           22-NOV-13 2.30.02.358 pm
6       1           22-NOV-13 10.30.02.358 PM
```

query should return:

```
date                    sum(actv)
-----                   ----------
Thursday work hours     11      
Thursday off hours      3       
friday work hours       7       
friday off hours        1
```

Comment: I have no idea how to do it. I manage to group by day and/or by hour but not by day from hour to hour.

Comment: There are 2 problems to solve here. (1) How do you tell if work or off hours? Answer = `EXTRACT(HOUR from start_date) between 8 and 16` (2) How to determine day of week? Answer = `to_char(start_date,'DAY')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version puts what you want in three columns:

```
select to_char(start_date, 'Day') as dow,
       (case when extract(hour from start_date) between 8 and 19
             then 'work/on hours'
             else 'work/off hours'
        end) as period,
       sum(actv)
from sess_actv
group by to_char(start_date, 'Day'),
         (case when extract(hour from start_date) between 8 and 19
               then 'work/on hours'
               else 'work/off hours'
          end)
```